# Case insensitive string replacement in Python

Tags: python, replace, case-insensitive

To make multiple case insensitive string replacement I'm using regex pattern, e.g.

```
import re
text = "Mentioning of reD, GrEen and BLUE is prohibited"
new_text = re.sub(r'(red|green|blue)', "***", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(new_text)
```

What would be the best way to make a pattern from a list (instead of entering it manually)?

```
words_to_replace = ["red", "green", "blue"]
```

Thanx in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

You can join with the pipe character

```
"|".join(["red", "green", "blue"])
```

This can fail if the words themselves have `|` or other meta characters that could potentially mess up the pattern. A regex injection attack... to coin a phrase.

```
import re
text = "Mentioning of reD, GrEen and BLUE is prohibited"
words_to_replace = ["red", "green", "blue"]
new_text = re.sub(f'({"|".join(words_to_replace)})', "***", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(new_text)
```

Comment: slight typo in your example. Should be `"|".join(["red", "green", "blue"])`